# Model relations, adding multiple models to database with ASP.Net MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a simple application with ASP.Net MVC and Entity Framework.

I have 3 tables:

1. **Workers:** It's pretty clear.
2. **ExtraHours:** It's related to one worker. Every ExtraHour has a relation with a worker. When ExtraHour record gets created, new Payment record should be created too. It has a field named WorkerId.
3. **Payments:** Payments to workers. Every Payment has a relation with a Worker. A payment can be related to ExtraHour but it's not required. It has a field named WorkerId. It doesn't have any field about ExtraHours so there is no way to relate one payment to a ExtraHour record, i don't want that.

First we create a worker. We can create ExtraHour about a Worker. It's pretty easy, basically i'm using the ExtraHour model. Things gets complicated when i try to add Payment record. Because PaymentAmount gets calculated like this:

```
payments.PaymentAmount = user.ExtraHourSalary * extraHour.Amount;
```

So i don't have any form field for **PaymentAmount**. I need to calculate that by getting user info (user.ExtraHourSalary). Here is the two questions:

- What kind of model should i use for this? Like i said, there is no direct relation between ExtraHour and Payment but new Payment record should be created when i create an ExtraHour record.
- In what controller should i add this record? Yes, it's a OverHour record but i need to create a Payment too. Should i create a new ViewModel includes all of this? It seems weird to me because it is called ViewModel.
- Should i just **"add payments.PaymentAmount = user.ExtraHourSalary * extraHour.Amount;"** code to controller code, in Create method or something like that?

I'm so confused and i hope it's clear enough, thanks.

Comment: do you have a controller dedicated to adding ExtraHours?  ex ExtraHoursController

Comment: @JamieD77 Yes, i do.

Comment: seems like that would be the logical place to add a new Payment if you add a new Payment every time an ExtraHour is created

Comment: for auditing purposes you could add `ExtraHourId` to `Payment` so you can tell how the payment got calculated

Comment: Yes, it seems logical but i wonder if it's right way to do it.